# Proving linearly independence even when the first vector is omitted

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Problem:

Let (A) $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$  be linearly independent vectors in a vector space $V$. Prove that the vectors (B) $x_2, x_3,...,x_k$ are also linearly independent.

My thoughts:

Okay. To start off I know that since (A) is linearly independent, then $c_1x_1 + c_2x_2,+...,+c_kx_k = 0$ implies that $c_1 , c_2, ... c_k = 0$. Since only one of the vectors is omitted from (B) then since the vectors are still not linear combinations of each other then their coefficients still must be $0$ so that they can equal zero thus B is linearly independent.

Are my thoughts on the correct path to solving this?

Edit:

Given (B), we have $c_2x_2 + c_3x_3 +\dots +c_kx_k = 0 $ which has an equivalent equation of $c_2x_2 + c_3x_3 +\dots +c_kx_k + 0x_{k+1} = 0 $

Since this is a zero linear combination of a linearly independent collection, all the coefficients must be zero. Is this any better?

Comment: Surely you mean they are linearly INdependent in (B)?

Comment: "are also linearly dependent"... ?!

Comment: Something something matroid theory

Comment: Yes typo sorry.

Comment: "then $c_1x_1$, $c_2x_2$, $\ldots$, $c_k x_k$ implies that $c_1$, $c_2$, $\ldots$, $c_k=0$" does not make sense. Fix the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $c_2x_2+\ldots+c_nx_n=0$, where not every $c_i$ is zero. Now extend this sum to $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\ldots+c_nx_n$, where $c_1=0$.

I think that's the idea of your proof. Note: this is proving the contraposition.